# Getting sql injection vulnerability issue in checkMarx: asmx with input as list<string>

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, asmx

Getting vulnerability issue in checkMarx saying, The application constructs this SQL query by embedding an untrusted string into the query without proper sanitization.An attacker would be able to inject arbitrary syntax and data into the SQL query, by crafting a malicious
payload and providing it via the input.

asmx service:

```
    [WebMethod]
    public ProductList MethodName(List<string> UpcList)
    {
            //create table to pass it as a table type
            var table = new DataTable("tableName");
            //add column to the table
            table.Columns.Add("columnName", typeof(string));

            foreach (var productId in UpcList)
            {
                table.Rows.Add(productId );
            }
            SqlParameter parm1 = new SqlParameter("@UPCList", SqlDbType.Structured);
            parm1.Value = table;
                
            SqlParameter[] parameters = new[] { parm1};


            Database.ExecuteReader(connectionString, "SPNAME", parameters);
    }

   public static void ExecuteReader(string connectionString, string procedure, IEnumerable<SqlParameter> parameters)
        {
            using (SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
            {
                conn.Open();
                using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(procedure))
                {
                    command.Connection = conn;
                    command.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                    foreach (SqlParameter parameter in parameters)
                        command.Parameters.Add(parameter);
                    
                    fetch(new SafeDataReader(command.ExecuteReader()));
                }
                conn.Close();
            }
        }
```

Comment: Are you sure you've shared the actual code that's generating the issue? What does Database.ExecuteReader look like? Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: yes this is the code.

Comment: Maybe connectionString?? How is that constructed?

Comment: Does this tool provide any specific information about what triggered this warning?  The query itself is correctly using a parameter, but we don't know anything else about the code.  Maybe you have custom data access code that is unsafe?  Maybe the stored procedure itself is unsafe?

Comment: @mason included the ExecuteReader method

Comment: I dont think execute reader has the error. It it working fine for other web methods

Comment: Side note: for a TVP you need to add to the `SqlParameter` constructor the following properties `{ TypeName = "YourTableType", Direction = ParameterDirection.Input }` you can aso combine `Value` in that. I hope you are disposing your reader

Comment: Do you actually have "SPNAME" in your code? Or do you have some other value there?

Comment: It has someother name . I just added as a example

Comment: Then what name does it have? Is that name hardcoded, or does it come from user input? You changing random things in your code example makes it very difficult to tell what code you're actually working with, so it makes it very hard for us to help you.

Comment: Yes it is hardcoded SPName

Comment: Then you haven't actually shown any SQL Injection vulnerability in your question. The user input is properly parameterized (the only danger would be if you used dynamic SQL in your stored procedure and concatenated the values to form a command/query). So, either Checkmarx is wrong, or you've shown us the wrong code.

Comment: Ensure that the parameter type (Structured) been added to the checkMatrix. Hopefully that resolves this.

Comment: @Ilangeeran It working fine now. I removed the type from my code. Thanks for the help